# How to increment the inner loop index from its previous state in XSL

Tags: .net, xslt, xsl-fo

How to increment the inner loop index from its previous state in XSL. what could the best approach, whether to maitain a seperate global variable best or use any inbuilt function. I am new to XSL so, please suggest

Input XML

```
<A1>
   <X1> ZERO </X1>   
</A1>
<A1>
   <X1> A </X1>
   <X1> B </X1>
</A1>
<A1>
   <X1> C </X1>
   <X1> D </X1>
</A1>
<A1>
   <X1> E </X1>
   <X1> F </X1>
</A1>
```

Expected Output

```
Y1 1
Y1 2
Y1 3
Y1 4
Y1 5
Y1 6
```

With the following XSL I am getting

```
Y1 1
Y1 2
Y1 1
Y1 2
Y1 1
Y1 2
```

.

```
<xsl:for-each select="A1">
  <xsl:variable name="var:v50" select="position()" />
  <xsl:variable name="var:v51" select="userVBScript:FctNotEqual(string(X1/text()),"ZERO")" />
   <xsl:if test="$var:v51">
     <xsl:for-each select="X1">
       <xsl:variable name="var:v52" select="position()" />
       <Y1>
         <xsl:value-of select="$var:v52" />
       </Y1>  
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

could you suggest with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved more simply with a single `xsl:for-each` with a predicate filter to select only the desired elements:

```
<xsl:for-each select="A1/X1[not(normalize-space()='ZERO')]">
    <Y1>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </Y1>  
</xsl:for-each>
```